# vuejs 3: importing svg templates cause: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module

Tags: import, dynamic, module, vuejs3, components

I have this template for svg icons, each icon is in a seperate file:

```
LoginIcon.vue
<template>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11 16l-4-4m0 0l4-4m-4 4h14m-5 4v1a3 3 0 01-3 3H6a3 3 0 01-3-3V7a3 3 0 013-3h7a3 3 0 013 3v1" />
    </svg>
</template>
```

when I want to use it I call like this:

```
<Button
    :variant="'primary'"
    :icon="'./outline/LoginIcon.vue'"
    type="submit"
    :class="'justify-center w-full gap-2'"
    :disabled="loading"
>
    <span>{{ language[zaban].login.Log_in }}</span>
</Button>
```

In Button.vue component :

```
    import BaseIcon from "@/components/tools/base/BaseIcon.vue";
```

Then

```
    <BaseIcon v-if="icon" :path="icon" :klass="iconClass" />
```

Here is the BaseIcon.vue component:

```
<template>
    <component :is="dynamicComponent" :class="klass"/>
</template>
<script setup>
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
  const props = defineProps({
    path: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    klass: {
      type: Array,
      default: 'h-6 w-6'
    },
  });
  const dynamicComponent = computed(()=>{
    return defineAsyncComponent( () => import(/* @vite-ignore */`${props.path.replace('./', '../../../icons/')}`) )
  })  
</script>
```

This works fine locally, but then I build an upload to server, problems starts.
The error is:
`Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://admin.hesabroshan.ir/icons/outline/LoginIcon.vue`

So I thought it does not have this route, I created icons folder and uploaded all vue files, same error.
Also uploaded files to asset folder too, same error.
**Note**: server is a shared windows with Plesk Obsidian 18.0.54 web host edition.